# Button changes position when text in two lines

Tags: android, layout

Hi I have this simple Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_trigger_left"
    style="@style/triggerButton"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:text="Mold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_trigger_right"
    style="@style/triggerButton"
    android:text="Fums" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and style is here.

```
<style name="triggerButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dip</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">2</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/symptom_bg</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dip</item>
</style>
```

and out put is like this.
[image]

it is ok, but when My text is long enough to two lines button comes down like this.

[image]

please help me when I am doing wrong ?
Thanks!

Comment: what if apply a margintop=0dp?

Comment: what is you target sdk? and what version of ADT you are using?

Comment: did you try to set `gravity` of the `linearlayout` to `Top`?

Comment: see my answer, you where setting wrong gravity in style.xml

Comment: just put this android:baselineAligned="false"  in your linear layout,it will work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put

> android:baselineAligned="false"

in your LinearLayout.

LinearLayout aligns the baselines of all its child controls by default and here you need to disable the behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
 <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:gravity">top</item>
```

Set gravity in your `style.xml` as this. Hope this will help.

Comment: @Rajesh CP But this is not a solution,it will put text to the top position,not center

Answer (score 0):

Fix maximum length of your text in Button

```
android:maxLength="20"
```

Hope this will help.